# php code to connect with Mysql database not apply

Tags: php, sql

[image]

when i click in submit in form

**Error**:

`insert into user (user_name,tel,password,isAdmin) VALUES ('dfd','555,' 443434','0')`

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '443434','0')' at line 2

Comment: check for the datatype

Comment: Could you post the code in the image?

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing quote just after 555 (`,'555,'` *i.e. $usertel* parameter ), Use `'555','443434'...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a quote before `$userpassword`